# Bounding global matrix coefficient for PGL_2

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm trying to find a reference that gives a bound for the adelic matrix coefficient for $\text{PGL}_2$ using the bound towards Ramanujan conjecture. More specifically:

Let $G=\text{PGL}_2$. Let $F$ be a number field. Let $X=G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}_F)$. Let $K=\prod_p K_p$ where $K_p$ is a locally maximal compact subgroup at $p$.
Let $h_i, i=1,2$ be elements in $L^2(X)$ which are rapidally decreasing and $K-$finite, and contain no components from 1-dim representations. (To be more specific, the $h_i$ we are going to take 
is essentially a product of two cusp forms.) Let $<\cdot,\cdot>$ denotes the natural pairing on $L^2(X)$.

Let $\varpi_p$ be a local uniformizer at $p$. Let $\mathcal{N}=\prod_{p}\varpi_p^{e_p}$ be a conductor, where $e_p\geq 0$ and equal to zero for almost all primes. Let $N=\text{Nm}(\mathcal{N})=\prod_p q^{e_p}$ where $q$ is the cardinality of the residue field at $p$. 
Let $0\leq\alpha<1/2$ be a bound towards Ramanujan conjecture
for $G$. Define
$$a(\mathcal{N})=\prod_{p}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\varpi_p^{-e_p}&0\\0&1
\end{array}\right).$$

I'm wondering if there is some work already on bounding $<\rho(a(\mathcal{N}))h_1, h_2>$ in terms of $N$. In particular I'd be happy to see some bound like the following:
 $$<\rho(a(\mathcal{N}))h_1, h_2>\ll_{\epsilon, F} \dim(Kh_1)^{1/2}\dim(Kh_2)^{1/2}N^{\alpha-1/2+\epsilon}||h_1||_{L^2}||h_2||_{L^2}$$

This result seems to follow from a direct product of local bound (9.1) in Venkatesh's paper *Sparse equidistribution problems, period bounds and subconvexity*, with the assumption that $h_i$ only has discrete spectrum(which is not the case if $h_i$ is a product of two cusp forms), and the primes appearing in $\mathcal{N}$ is controlled(for example, fixed finite). I'm not sure how to deal with the continuous spectrum in general.

Comment: Check out equation 2.10 in section 2.5.2 of this paper: (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3591v2.pdf)

Comment: Indeed that's a global upper bound, although in terms of Sobolev norm. I will try to see if it will give the bound that I need. Thank you very much for the reference.